# MSMQ Application does not process queued messages when running as Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, msmq

This is a straight forward question:

My application behaves correctly when running as a standard program. Now when I run it as a windows service, it does not process the messages in it's private queue (using MSMQ).

I tried running the service as both my user account and as a LOCAL SERVICE. In both cases, the queue just filled up with messages, none of them being processed.

**Note that the Windows Service seems to be running correctly: it's associated Wcf service is opened and listening.**

Just to make sure it wasn't a permission problem, I granted full access to every group/user I could think of. Here is the code dealing with the queue creation and host initialisation. Note that in this attempt, I changed the localized naming of users to their english counterpart. Also note that I tried to install the service under all possible accounts: my own running as admin, LocalSystem, LocalService and NetworkService.

```
namespace MachineCommunication.ZeissCMMAdapter
{
    partial class ZeissService : ServiceBase
    {
        public ZeissService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        ServiceHost _host = null;

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Starting ZeissAdapter Service...");
            string adapterQueueName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["adapterQueueName"];

            // Create the transacted MSMQ queue if necessary.

            MessageQueue adapterQueue;
            if (!MessageQueue.Exists(adapterQueueName))
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Creating Queue: " + adapterQueueName);
                adapterQueue = MessageQueue.Create(adapterQueueName, true);
                adapterQueue.SetPermissions(@"NT AUTHORITY\System", MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl);
                adapterQueue.SetPermissions(@"ANONYMOUS LOGON", MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl);
                adapterQueue.SetPermissions(@"Everyone", MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl);
                adapterQueue.SetPermissions(@"my_user", MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl);
            }
            else
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Queue already exists: " + adapterQueueName);
            }


            string machineQueueName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["machineQueueName"];
            MessageQueue machineQueue;
            // Create the transacted MSMQ queue if necessary.
            if (!MessageQueue.Exists(machineQueueName))
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Creating Queue: " + machineQueueName);
                machineQueue = MessageQueue.Create(machineQueueName, true);
                machineQueue.SetPermissions(@"NT AUTHORITY\System", MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl);
                machineQueue.SetPermissions(@"ANONYMOUS LOGON", MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl);
                machineQueue.SetPermissions(@"Everyone", MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl);
                machineQueue.SetPermissions(@"my_user", MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl);
            }
            using (_host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ZeissAdapterService)))
            {
                _host.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("The service is ready");
                Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            try
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Shutting down Class-A E-mail Service...");
                if (_host != null && _host.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
                {
                    _host.Close();
                    _host = null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Something went wrong closing the ServiceHost : " + ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the full app.config for my service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- use appSetting to configure MSMQ queue name -->
    <add key="adapterQueueName" value=".\private$\Zeiss/ZeissAdapterService"/>
    <add key="machineQueueName" value=".\private$\Zeiss/ZeissMachineService"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MachineCommunication.ZeissCMMAdapter.ZeissAdapterService" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior">
        <!-- Define NetMsmqEndpoint -->
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:12000/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/private/Zeiss/ZeissAdapterService" binding="netMsmqBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransactedBinding" contract="MachineCommunication.Contracts.AdapterContracts.IAdapterService"/>
        <endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/private/Zeiss/ZeissMachineService" binding="netMsmqBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransactedBinding" contract="MachineCommunication.MachineTypeSpecificInfrastructure.ZeissInfrastructure.IZeissListener"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <netMsmqBinding>
        <binding name="TransactedBinding" deadLetterQueue="System" useActiveDirectory ="False" useMsmqTracing="True">
          <security mode="None">
            <message clientCredentialType="None"/>
            <transport msmqAuthenticationMode="None" msmqProtectionLevel="None"  />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netMsmqBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="sdt"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "SdrConfigExample.e2e" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Here is a somewhat quick way to reproduce the issue: In the WCF code samples distributed on MSDN, there is a Two-Way MSMQ sample involving a client/server setup; I modified this sample to install the server as a Windows Service. If you run the server and launch the client, all messages should end up stuck in the server's queue without being further processed. Here is a link to that sample:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5-APK5bfBpMUGU2cW5iaV9ybnM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue was simply that I tried to stop the service thread from exiting with a console.readline -  which (obviously perhaps) is not applicable when running an application as a service. My bad, I'm really sorry to have asked the question in the first place. Thanks anyhow for all the answers attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of thoughts.

1. Try allowing the service to run as you, but as an interactive user.
2. Is the configuration file in the correct folder?  When you run a windows service, it defaults the base directory for the appdomain to the %SYSDIR% (which you can override in the OnStart)

Beyond that, I'd recommend adding in a tracer and logging what activity is actually happening or attaching to process with debugger.

If you need to override the BaseDir.

```
System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely due to rights. Windows Services running under Network Service or so don't have rights to access MSMQ queues. You'll have to provide access.

Try this on a development computer or test server, not on production. Try giving "Everyone" rights to the queues you're talking to and run the service under a user that has administrative rights. If it starts processing messages then, you'll know it's a rights issue.

Then narrow it down. Remove more and more rights to see if it's still working.

Also try some logging to see if the service is starting correctly. Try loading configuration settings and log them. Try viewing them with Sysinternals DebugView or log them to file. If the service is logging to file and you see the proper configuration item value being logged, you'll know it's not a problem there.

What I've also seen is that people think they should access a queuename/service.svc queue. But this is only for IIS hosted WCF services.

If I was you, post the entire configuration. You're not providing a lot of information and I can't see if anything's wrong with the configuration either.

Comment: Sorry for the localized users/groups in the code above. Actually, I did gave full access to "Everyone" (Tout le monde), NETWORK SERVICE (SERVICE RÉSEAU), LOCAL SERVICE, etc. I also tried to run the service as my own user (with admin rights), as Local service, as local system as a Network Service. The queue always remained still (I did deleted it and assigned full rights to every account I could think of before each attempt). I'll edit my post to include more of the code that could be responsible for the issue. Thanks for your response!

Comment: What if you programatically set the binding to MSMQ? I have the feeling it is not using the App.config to listen via MSMQ, but instead is using default values to listen on Http

I forgot what the exact syntax is, but it's something like:
_host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MachineCommunication.MachineTypeSpecificInfrastructure.ZeissInfrastructure.IZeissListener),
                    new NetTcpBinding(),
                    "SomeName");

And also it's impossible to have two listeners on the same MSMQ queue. You should both provide them with their own queue. Remove one from configuration to test.